# php - how select data from database and set to single row if duplicate

Tags: php, html, mysql

what I want to is when I select from database set the duplicate value into one row.

On my result, on genre column the data is not in one row.

So on the genre column, how to set the genre data into one row?

Example the result in one row :Drama, Western, Romance

**Table (movie_genre):**

[image: Table movie_genre]

**Table (genre):**

[image: Table genre]

**Result:**

[image: result]

PHP/HTML code:

```
<?php
 $categorySql = "SELECT DISTINCT movie.id,movie.name,genre.type,movie.price,movie.language,movie.subtitle,movie.director,movie.cast,movie.runningtime FROM movie INNER JOIN movie_genre ON movie.id = movie_genre.movie_id INNER JOIN genre ON genre.id = movie_genre.genre_id";

 if ($categoryStmt = $conn->prepare($categorySql)) {
/* execute query */
$categoryStmt->execute();

 $categoryStmt->bind_result($id, $name, $genre, $price, $language, $subtitle, 
$director, $cast, $time);


$rows = array();


while ($categoryStmt->fetch()) {
    $row = array(
        'id' => $id,
        'name' => $name,
        'genre' => $genre,
        'price' => "RM " . $price,
        'language' => $language,
        'subtitle' => $subtitle,
        'director' => $director,
        'cast' => $cast,
        'runningtime' => $time . " mins"

    );
    $rows[] = $row;
}
}
$categoryStmt->close();
?>

<div class="movielisttable">
<table id="movielist_table">
    <tr id="">
        <th>ID:</th>
        <th>Movie Name</th>
        <th>Genre</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Language</th>
        <th>Subtitle</th>
        <th>Director</th>
        <th>Cast</th>
        <th>Running Time</th>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
    <?php
    foreach ($rows as &$value) {
        echo
        "<tr>
          <td>{$value['id'] }</td>
          <td>{$value['name']}</td>
          <td>{$value['genre']}</td>
          <td>{$value['price']}</td>
          <td>{$value['language']}</td>
          <td>{$value['subtitle']}</td>
          <td>{$value['director']}</td>
          <td>{$value['cast']}</td>
          <td>{$value['runningtime']}</td>

        </tr>\n";
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be you are looking for group_concat  and group by

```
  $categorySql = "SELECT 
        movie.id
        ,movie.name
        , group_concat(genre.type) as type
        ,movie.price
        ,movie.language
        ,movie.subtitle
        ,movie.director
        ,movie.cast
        ,movie.runningtime 
  FROM movie 
  INNER JOIN movie_genre ON movie.id = movie_genre.movie_id 
  INNER JOIN genre ON genre.id = movie_genre.genre_id
  GROUP BY  movie.id ";
```

Comment: If you find yourself sticking DISTINCT and GROUP BY into the same query, you can be sure that your caffeine levels are severely depleted.

Comment: @Strawberry   .. correct  .. answer update  ..  distinct removed ... caffein level  .?   ..  .  minor problem..   ... i think age ..

Comment: Incidentally, to my way of thinking, there is almost no problem in sql for which GROUP_CONCAT need form any part of the answer - least of all where the result is then parsed in application code

Comment: in mysql  the use of this aggregation function simplifies the result and reduce  the application code for selective concat of the result  ..